# Issue with node.js require.paths.unshift()

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js world, I'm using node.js v0.8.4. I googled for this issue. Yes, i got solutions for this, but still could not understand as a beginner. So please help me......

i was going through a node.js tutorial. In that tutorial node.js v0.1.103 is used and he writes

```
require.paths.unshift(__dirname+'/vendor');

var http = require('http'),
sys = require('sys'),
nodeStatic = require('node-static/lib/node-static');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
var file = new nodeStatic.Server('./public', function() {
    cache: false
    });
request.addListener('end', function() {
    file.server(request, response);
    });
}).listen(8000);
```

And the script above works for him. When i write the sample script and run, i get this error.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\local>node C:\xampp\htdocs\rt\node\livestats\
server.js

Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH envi
ronment variable instead.
at Function.Module._compile.Object.defineProperty.get (module.js:386:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\rt\node\livestats\server.js:2:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

How do i make node to load files from custome directory and How to i solve this issue? My OS is windows

Thank you......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require.paths` is deprecated a long time ago. The tutorial for node v0.1 is pretty much useless now, as nearly everything has changed since then.

If you installed `node-static` with `npm install`, you can just use `require("node-static")` without specifying the entire path (and, of course, without using `require.paths`).

Comment: Hello penartur;
Thanks for replying, now i have a new issue, to server node_modules for node script. In my command line have set the node path

    set NODE_PATH=c:\..\node_modules.

This works when i do require('express');

But when i restart my system, require('express'); will not work, it says express module is not found. When i again set my NODE_PATH via command line. It will work fine.

So how to set my NODE_PATH,so that it wont changes when i restart my system.

Thank you so much......

Comment: Did you referenced `express` in your project `package.json` file? Did you run `npm install -d` from your project root folder?